# Custom byte serializer

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, serialization

I have a dictionary of this type

```
Dictionary <byte, object> parameters = new Dictionary <byte, object> ();
```

As I write `object` data types `int, long, float`, etc.

I need to serialize this list into an array of bytes to be transmitted over the network. But here comes the problem: how do you know which type is in the `object`? There iedya record into an array of bytes from one byte prefix which will contain the type of the variable. But you need to first know what type is in the object, once compare types, all this strongly loads a program. Maybe you have an idea how you can quickly and efficiently serialize this dictionary?

Now I have a code like this:

Class BinarySerializer

```
public static byte [] Serialize (short value) // get an array of bytes
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes (value);
}
```

class where the serialization:

```
byte [] msg = new byte [256];

int offset = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair <byte, object> pair in message.Parameters)
{
    msg [offset ++] = pair.Key;

    byte [] array = new byte [0];
    byte [] buffer;
    if (pair.Value.GetType (). Equals (typeof (short)))
    {
        msg [offset ++] = 1; // variable type
        buffer = BinarySerializer.Serialize ((short) pair.Value);
    }

    Buffer.BlockCopy (buffer, 0, msg, 0, buffer.Length);

    offset + = buffer.Length;
}
```

Comment: You are using BlockCopy the wrong way. Your Source array is always the empty `array == byte[0]`

Comment: Sorry, little mistake here

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? You ask " how do you know which type is in the object?" - but you already have `pair.Value.GetType()` in use, which is indeed one way... I'm assuming the `1; // variable type` identifies it during deserialization; so... what is left unknown? You *could* use a few other approaches, like `is` tests, or `switch(Type.GetTypeCode(...))`, but....

Comment: Note: in most serialization contexts, it is a **terrible** idea for intermediate methods to *return* a `byte[]` - that's a lot of allocations etc. It would be more typical to *pass the buffer in* along with the offset, (or: pass a `Stream`), and have the various `Serialize` methods *write to it*

Comment: Its works, but slowly. Compare type of each variable is not good at all, may be there is a better way to approach this

Comment: "Its works, but slowly" - yes, but which bit is the "slowly" here? since the values are already boxed, the `.GetType()` is pretty damned cheap. This makes me suspect that any slowness: is elsewhere. All those allocations would be my first guess... (2 `byte[]` *per parameter*? just... *why?*)

Comment: I have to ask: would it be sufficient to just use a pre-existing serialization library like protobuf-net? There are a *lot* of challenges to explain in this space... much more than can be explained in a single stackoverflow post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its works, but slowly. Compare type of each variable is not good at all,

In that case, consider:

```
switch(Type.GetTypeCode(pair.Value.GetType()))
{
    case TypeCode.Int16: // aka short
       // ...
    // etc
}
```

But the more likely cause of performance issues here is allocations. Without a wider context of your code, and evidence of why you think it is slow: we can't comment much.

If you want blistering performance, though: *don't use a dictionary*. Consider:

```
var obj = new {
   Name = "Fred",
   Age = 18,
   IsActive = true
};
```

That is a fully typed `class` with named, typed values. You can use meta-programming (typically IL-emit or `Expression`) to process such types *very* efficiently (as long as you cache the generated strategies). That is the approach that fully-developed serialization libraries like JSON.NET or protobuf-net use.

Comment: Thanks alot, ill try it now